# SQLLDR format single digit month and date

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

in my sqlldr ctl file i have the below entry

```
REPORT_MONTH "decode(trim(:REPORT_MONTH),null,null,to_date(trim(:REPORT_MONTH), 'MMYYYY'))"
```

but this fails if data is 22018 pass for 022018. I know in java it supports 'MYYYY' but what i found after searching is SQL does not have such format. Then how do i parse date with single digits?

And also i have another field where single digit month and date should be allowed, something like '9/9/2018'

```
DISP_DATE "decode(trim(:DISP_DATE),null,null,to_date(trim(:DISP_DATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY'))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you need to pad the date out to six characters, filling in with zeroes on the left. In the second case it will work just fine using a formatting string of `'MM/DD/YYYY'`. The following example shows how to accomplish this:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(LPAD('22018', 6, '0'), 'MMYYYY') AS SIX_DIGIT_DATE,
       TO_DATE('9/9/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EIGHT_DIGIT_DATE
  FROM DUAL;
```

Best of luck.